# Platform Integration User Access to Manage Package

Tags: managed-package, fls

I developed and published free app in the AppExchagne.
It does check the security access to fields/object as best practice.

In subscriber org there is process running by user "Platform Integration User". This user doesn't have profile and seems cannot have permission set therefore he doesn't have access to the package fields and any process that the package runs skipped for the user.

Is there any way to provide this user access to the package objects/fields?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by skipping the FLS check for this specific user.
I actually wrote in the code

```
If UserInfo.getName() == 'Platform Integration User'){
    //skip check
}
```

note that you can run script to assign this user permission set.
Like:

```
insert new PermissionSetAssignment (PermissionSetId = permissionSetId, AssigneeId = userId);
```

However, I found that in some cases related to managed package it is not being respected